# how docker container can get IP where docker swarm runs

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm, discovery

So my application server (instance with swarm installed) and many clients (docker containers on a different physical nodes) require that clients should connect to server by hostname and I don't know how container can get node IP where swarm runs to be able to connect.
I know that I can pass hosts rules to each docker container with hostname and IP of the node where swarm runs but I don't know how to get that IP because there is a lot of interfaces with different IPs.

So generally I'm looking for something like docker client can ask swarm what is your IP to be able to connect back.

Comment: Resolving a network address from a host name is what DNS does.